# VS2019 DataSet Designer Mangling INSERT queries - Removing RETURNING statements

Tags: visual-studio, npgsql, strongly-typed-dataset

Yes, it's 2021 and I am still using DataSets!  But, it still works mostly ...

However, I am having an issue that is slowly driving me crazy.  I have several projects using PostgreSQL database and DataSets.  The issue causing me grief is that while using MS SQL Server databases, tables with identity keys have no issues in updating the DataTable and returning the keys following the update.  With postgres, we need to add a RETURNING id statement at the end of the INSERT query or use a SELECT currval().  Which by itself is fine. But, if you then edit the DataTable in any fashion (add a query to it for example), it trumps the insert query and turfs the parameter provided to handle the return value.

Is there any known way around this, or am I missing something simple?  For the previous 20 years I worked almost exclusively with MS SQL Server and it just works ...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Likely a bug in the generator - do you have "refresh the datatable" turned on in the TA wizard? PG wouldn't be the only provider to have issues with it if you do.. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=99199

Comment: If you can't find an in-VS solution, you might have some success in using(creating) an external program (or your version control system) to revert the unintended changes/merge the unintended and the intended